# Mysql synchcronization between update and read event

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am working in a sensors project where many sensors outputs data which are stored in mysql table. I am using highcharts to visualize those data.

My problem is when I use the live mode, with an ajax call every second to my database, some data are not displayed since the ajax call fetch only the latest one and some points are dropped default of synchronization between the time when I push the data from sensors and the time to fetch them with ajax. I tried to synchronize this manually but I failed .

I am asking if there is a parameter that I can add to my sql queries to fetch only the data which has not been read yet, like this  even if I push 3 data in one second with an ajax call made in on second I get only the not read data not the latest one.

I don't know if this solution really exist and I am pretty new in php and mysql and I use them for research purpose only ,I need the simplest and the minimum solution !!

EDITI:: create new table last_point with last_point_id and last_point_info

I am using yii framework,  I couldn't make an update query using yii library
so I used this code

```
$modelSensor = SensorInfo2::model()->findBySql('SELECT * FROM information_sensors  
         where sensors_id= "'.$s['sensors_id'].'"  ; ');    


   $sResult = array(intval($modelSensor->information_time ),intval($modelSensor-

                                                        >information_value ));

        foreach ($modelSensor as $up) // for each value that I get from previous query 
                                       //   I want to use it to  
                                        //    update  last_point table

          {

        $connection = yii::app()->db;

         $sql = 'UPDATE last_point  SET last_point_info = 
         "'.$up['information_time'].'"' ;

         $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
         $command->execute();


         }

        $json = CJSON::encode($sResult);

            echo $json ;

            Yii::app()->end();
```

for my ajax query not problem and I still get  my data, but the row last_point_info in the other table change to zero !
Any idea ? how the two tables should be connected ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write a qurey which tells give the points whose creationDates are later than the lastRetrieved points. smtg like this: SELECT points.name FROM points WHERE points.creationDate > 'lastRetrievedDate'

Comment: thanks cubbuk , the points.creationDate and lastRetrievedDate are defined as rows in my table? and how those rows are updated 
my atble is sensors_info it contains point_id, point_time , point_value 
many thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 2 cdbcreteria one for geting the condition and another to get mydata using the first cdbcreteria as condition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763774/cdbcriteria-condition-from-another-cdbcriteria)

and finaly I update the time in the other table with foreach statement with this code

```
foreach ($sensors as $sensor)  {
 $lastPointId = 1;  
 $lastPoint = LastPoint::model()->findByPk($lastPointId);
 $lastPoint->last_point_info = $sensor->information_time;
 if ( ! $lastPoint->save()) {
throw new CException('Unable to save last point.');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the last retrieve time of the last point. You may keep it in a memory variable or if you want you can keep it in a database table to persist it. Assume that you keep lastRetrievedTime in another table called lastPoint.

Then to retrieve the points came after the last point you neea a query smtg like this

SELECT point_id, point_name, point_time 
FROM sensors_info, lastPoint
WHERE point_time > lastPoint.lastRetrievedTime
ORDER BY point_time ASC
LIMIT 3

This query will turn you the first 3 points that are collected after the last point you retrieved in your application. If you remove the `LIMIT` option it will return you all the points that are retrieved after the last retrieved point. After retrieving last point you just need to update the lastPoint table so that it again keeps the lastRetrieved time in its record.

Cheers

Comment: many thanks! I suppose that I add a row named lastRetrieved_time so after the point is retrieved how to collect this time and put it in the corresponding field.(I heard about trigger after select, is it true ?)
I need only one point by select.
That means if I have in my table 100 entries and the last 10 are not retrieved yet, my query should give me point the point 91, 92 ....and so on until all data are retrieved in order.
Even there is an update in same time, my data become 110 but my query give me point 91 ....

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you can keep the lastRetrievedTime in a table. And about your last point you are correct, you will retrieve points 91 and so on even though some new points arrived at the time you make the query.

Comment: I understand your idea, lastRetrievedTime is a propriety of mysql? how the records in table last_point are made when a point is retrieved from sensors_info table ? sorry I really know only simple select in mysql! thanks

Comment: Well you need to update that table yourself with another query like this. `UPDATE last_point SET lastRetrievedTime = 'lastRetrievedTimeYouHave'` This command will update all the records on last_point table but since you have only one record on that table this won't be a problem otherwise you would need to give a WHERE clause to UPDATE query.

Comment: Hi , I get strange update of my table last_point .
any idea ?
thanks

Comment: the value last_point_info become 0 after the update instead to information_time

Comment: Can you post your update statement? Also I suggest you to read some tutorial on SQL, it will help you a lot to solve such problems.

Comment: I edited my first post to show my update statement, I refered to many post in this forum and I some SQL tutorial. Many thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with php or Yii Framework, but your query doesn't seem wrong. Only strange thing is that you should also update the point id since you store it on the table. Btw do you have any record in the table, if not the update won't work?

Comment: I put some random data in the last_point_info , and after that the data become zero, I don't know exactly from where the problem, may be that I am not using YII library to do the update.

Comment: what is the schema of your table? What does `.$up['information_time'].` return, what is the type of it?

Comment: I also updated the id as you requested, and it's ok the last_point_id is updated with the value that I put in my query.

Comment: No, only the id is updated correctly, the other field still zero! I think something missing in teh table configuration(primary key ....)