# CDbCriteria condition from another CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

I don't if that I want to do is possible or not, I have two models i want to get data from one model using a condition from another.

```
                    $criteria1=new CDbCriteria;
        $paramIds = $s['param_id'];
        $stress = model1::model()->find($criteria1);
        $mycondition= ($stress->stress_value);

        echo $mycondition ; // I get this value and I want to use it as  
                                        // condition for the next cdbcreteria

        $criteria2=new CDbCriteria;

                     // condition
        $criteria2->addcondition(array('pressure_value' >  $mycondition));

                      // I can't  perform this condition       

        $criteria2->order = "pressure_value desc";
        $pressure = model2::model()->find($criteria2);
```

Any idea ? my code is wrong or what I want to do is not possible in this way ?

Many thanks

Comment: If `$mycondition` is just a number, try `$criteria2->addcondition('pressure_value >'. $mycondition)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, $mycondition is a time , I want to compare to value of pressure for 2 given time

Comment: Do it like this then: `$criteria2->addCondition('pressure_value > :value');` and `$criteria2->params(array(':value' => $mycondition))`. This way Yii will properly escape the value.

Comment: thansk again , I get error CDbCriteria and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "params" ! but in the yii documentation there is this method http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#params-detail

Comment: Oh, I guess it's not a function then. `$criteria2->params = array(':value' => $mycondition)` should work.

Comment: yes it work, but the error now is  " CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Comment: what is the full SQL statement it's showing you on the error page?

Comment: thanks Stu, I find the solution which consit of making the compare statement in cdbcreteria after the condition. But now the problem is the return value for cdbcreteria2 I canot make echo to this value and I can use it for foreach statement. the returned value is 0 with error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Örs

your solution work for me with making the compare statement in cdbcreteria after the condition

```
$criteria2->params = array(':value' => $mycondition)
```